# Schengen (France) proof sufficient financial means

Tags: schengen, france, proof-provenance-of-funds

American here, I am going to France next week, for a duration of 17 days.

I am confused about the documents I need to present, namely:

- **Proof of accommodation**: I will be staying with my girlfriend.

  - Is there a way to avoid burdening my girlfriend with having to provide a "[certificate of staying with a relative validated in the town hall at the request of the person who invited you](https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en/web/France-visas/your-arrival-in-france)"? (<-- first section in link)

  which brings us to
- **Sufficient financial means**

  - "[120 euros per day in the case of non-presentation of a hotel booking;](https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en/web/France-visas/your-arrival-in-france)" (second section)

If I understand correctly, 17 days * 120 euros per day = 2040 euros.
If this is correct, do I show a bank statement?  If so, how recent must it be?

Thank you!

---

#### What Actually Happened

I was not asked for proof of funds, travel guard insurance, or anything (as [willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke) kindly and correctly pointed out).  I was given a perfunctory glance and had my passport stamped, and that was it.  Thank for your response!

But of course they would have been well within their right to ask for it, as [relaxed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6669/relaxed) pointed out.  Rules are rules, and can be enforced at any time, so better to have it and not need it, then need it and not have it (as my father was wont to say).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a US citizen visiting a Schengen country it is very likely you will not even be asked about money, but you might be and in that case you better show you have a credit card which will cover the needed money for a hotel, or the last few bank statements which show your monthly income coming in, and/or a savings account that holds enough money.

It is again very unlikely that you will need the money for staying in a hotel and eating out three times a day, and you may want to look up a hostel in the area if you do not have a regular income which will cover that much money.
So if you are challenged on the amount of money you explain that you expect to stay with your friend and if something happens, you are planning to use a hostel instead, (with the added benefit that you can cook your own meals from supermarket supplies.)

But it is the best to have those 2040€ in your bank and/or savings account.
(If you can not have 2500US$ in your accounts, can you afford to travel to Europe?)

Comment: You're right that this is extremely unlikely to come up but if it does your ability to live frugally or the actual price of hostels is completely irrevelant. At that point, border guards are looking for a reason to refuse entry and you really want to show you have ample financial means, not suggest you're under the formal threshold. Staying with friends is also irrelevant as that's precisely what the certificate is about. It makes no sense to bring it up and expect border guards to act as if it was a legally established fact when you refused to go through the proper procedure beforehand.